# SQL SORTING ISSUE WITH GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

```
SELECT TOP 10 tb_show.showId, tb_Show.Title, tb_Show.PageName, Quantity
FROM         tb_OrderItem INNER JOIN
                        (SELECT * FROM tb_Show WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND PrivateShow = 0 AND Archive = 0 ) tb_Show
                      ON tb_OrderItem.ShowId = tb_Show.showId             
GROUP BY tb_show.showId, tb_Show.Title, tb_Show.PageName, Quantity
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

- 160  dsadsadsadsa    dsadsadsadsa    **3**
- 160  dsadsadsadsa    dsadsadsadsa    **2**
- 150  css based map test event    css-based-map-test-event    **1**
- 159  cross hollows test  cross-hollows-test  **1**

---

**But I dont want to repeat ID i.e. 160. So I made it subquery and get only three coloumns with `DISTINCT` keywords .. Issue is that sorting by quantity is not working when I move it into subquery with DISTINCT keywords without it sorting is fine but distinct keywords remove sorting...**

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 showId, Title, PageName  from 
( SELECT TOP 10 tb_show.showId, tb_Show.Title, tb_Show.PageName, Quantity
FROM         tb_OrderItem INNER JOIN
                        (SELECT * FROM tb_Show WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND PrivateShow = 0 AND Archive = 0 ) tb_Show
                      ON tb_OrderItem.ShowId = tb_Show.showId             
GROUP BY tb_show.showId, tb_Show.Title, tb_Show.PageName, Quantity
ORDER BY Quantity DESC ) tb_show
```

- 150  css based map test event    css-based-map-test-event
- 159  cross hollows test  cross-hollows-test
- 160  dsadsadsadsa    dsadsadsadsa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the output in your second example. The reason the distinct subquery wasn't working for you was because you were also grouping by quantity which caused separate distinct rows to be output.

```
SELECT TOP 10 tb_show.showId, tb_Show.Title, tb_Show.PageName, MAX(quantity) as Quantity
FROM tb_OrderItem 
    INNER JOIN tb_Show 
        ON tb_OrderItem.ShowId = tb_Show.showId 
WHERE tb_show.IsDeleted = 0 AND tb_show.PrivateShow = 0 AND tb_show.Archive = 0 
GROUP BY tb_show.showId, tb_Show.Title, tb_Show.PageName
ORDER BY MAX(quantity)
```

Comment: No but I want sorting as in first example ... because most sold quantity should be first.

Comment: I am trying to sort by quantity and my second example work fine if I remove distinct keywords but still it duplicates rows but as i placed distinct keyword it remove sorting

Comment: I WISH I COULD GIVE YOU TWO POINTS UP :)